# Extract All HTML tags from the particular page In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I need to extract all HTML tags from a webpage into an array without the data inside the tags using Capybara in Ruby

Comment: I'm curious, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) gem.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Fetch and parse HTML document
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.co.in'))

# To list all anchor tags, do:
doc.search('a').each{ |x| puts x.inspect }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in Capybara

```
find(:xpath, "//*")
```